# How to create JSONP callback?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I have JSON file generated on my server , but I want to access that data from other host . What should I do on my server , or JSON file to make that data accessible from other domains like JSONP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's exposed by some web-accessible method, you need to accept a `callback` (or similar) parameter which then just becomes a wrapper to the JSON data. e.g.

If you had:

```
/some/service.json
```

Which returned:

```
{"this":"is","JSON":"data"}
```

You then allow the service to be passed a `callback`:

```
/some/service.json?callback=foo
```

Which in turn results in:

```
foo({"this":"is","JSON":"data"})
```

That's all there really is to making the response adhere with JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

i think this below code help you

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "xyz.com",
    data: jsondata,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {

        if(data.flag == true){

            alert(data.msg);


        } else {
            alert("not sucess");

        }
    }

    });
```

Comment: This is client-side; My understanding is that the OP was asking how to make it available from server-side.